# How do I retrieve a field from a Many-To-Many table?

Tags: python, django, django-polymorphic

I need to retrieve a value from a Many-To-Many query. Let's say I have 3 models: Toy, Part, and ToyParts

ToyParts has a field called "part_no". I need to be able to get the value of this.

```py
class Toy(models.Model):
    parts = models.ManyToManyField(Part, through="ToyParts")

class Part(models.Model):
    pass

class ToyParts(models.Model):
    toy = models.ForeignKey(Toy, ...)
    part = models.ForeignKey(Part, ...)
    part_no = models.CharField(...)
```

I've tried using:

```py
toy.parts.all().first().part_no
```

which obviously doesn't work as Part does not have a field called "part_no"

I've also tried just simply using:

```py
ToyParts.objects.filter(toy=..., part=...)
```

but that adds additional queries.

How would I be able to get `part_no` without querying ToyParts directly?

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried using: `toy.parts.all().first().part_no`

The `part_no` field is declared on the model `ToyParts`. You therefore need to get an instance of `ToyParts` to access this field. Assuming you have a `Toy` instance you can use the reverse relation to `ToyParts`, which defaults to `toyparts_set`, as follows:

```py
toy.toyparts_set.first().part_no
```

> How would I be able to get `part_no` without querying ToyParts directly?

You can't. If you want to reduce the number of queries you can use `select_related`:

```py
for tp in toy.toyparts_set.select_related('part').all():
    print(tp.part_no, tp.part.id)
```

In this example `tp.part` doesn't require an extra query as the part instance is already fetched by `select_related`.